# rtmp and adobe media player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, streaming, rtmp

We have acquired hosting of a Flash Media Server for prototyping, and we are trying to stream videos using Adobe Media Player. While we know that this is possible, we are curious as to what steps are needed to do this:

Do we need to create a server side app in order to stream, or can we just host the videos?

We already have pre-existing feeds in AMP that currently consist of ordinary podcasts. We are aware that we will either need to modify the feeds or create new ones containing the urls to the rtmp streams. This question is not about the creation of these feeds, but more specifically about how you set up an rtmp stream in AMP.

Thanks

Comment: btw, adobe recently opened the RTMP protocol - http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/pressroom/pressreleases/200901/012009RTMP.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the server some more, and following [this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/beginner_vod_fm3.html) I seem to have figured it out.

For anyone else out there with the same question: You simply need to create a VOD application (our server did not have one installed by default, but have several out-of-the-box addons that got installed via point-and-click), place the videos in the instance folder (again, different on our hosted server), and place the url in the feed.